# Setup nrwl/nx workspace with angular universal, cypress typing issue

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, cypress, nrwl

## TL;DR

When running `yarn webpack:server` gives me the error `Cannot find name 'cy'.`

**Example repo:** [Branch showing error](https://github.com/stefan-karlsson/nx-workspace-with-ssr/tree/1906_serve-ssr)

---

## Error description

Hi, i am trying to setup a minimum viable product project to test [angular universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) within a [nrwl/nx workspace](https://nrwl.io/nx).

Most of the setup has been done using ng cli with nrwl/nx schematics:

- `create-nx-workspace nx-workspace-with-ssr --yarn`
- `ng g app nx-app` (jest & cypress for testing)
- `yarn update (update using the nrwl/nx schematic)`
- `ng g universal (nrwl/nx schematic for setting up universal)`

When this steps was done i tried to follow [the following guide](https://angular.io/guide/universal#step-4-set-up-a-server-to-run-universal-bundles) on how to *build and serve* the ssr application.

I changed the paths in the example scripts to match my nx project.

When running `yarn webpack:server` gives me the error `Cannot find name 'cy'.`

I think this is strange since i don't even want to build files from the `apps/nx-app-e2e/` folder. So i guess there is a problem with some of the `tsconfig*` files, but i can't seem to find the problem.

## Setup

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.0
Node: 10.14.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.0
@angular/cli                      7.3.0
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.3.0
@schematics/update                0.13.0
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.23.1
```

#### Failure Logs

```
$ yarn webpack:server
yarn run v1.13.0
$ webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors
Hash: d991a357a6372aad06d8
Version: webpack 4.23.1
Time: 8716ms
Built at: 02/06/2019 2:24:07 PM
 1 asset
Entrypoint server = server.js
  [1] ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js + 4 modules 974 KiB {0} [built] [2 warnings]
      |    5 modules
  [4] ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js + 2 modules 5.33 KiB {0} [built]
      |    3 modules
 [11] external "path" 42 bytes {0} [built]
 [12] ./node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm5/store.js + 10 modules 43.8 KiB {0} [built]
      |    11 modules
 [27] external "fs" 42 bytes {0} [built]
 [47] ./node_modules/@ngrx/effects/fesm5/effects.js + 4 modules 21.7 KiB {0} [built]
      |    5 modules
 [55] external "url" 42 bytes {0} [built]
 [85] external "events" 42 bytes {0} [built]
 [86] external "crypto" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[106] ./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm5/platform-server.js + 2 modules 1.24 MiB {0} [built]
      |    3 modules
[109] ./apps/nx-app/src lazy namespace object 160 bytes {0} [built]
[158] external "timers" 42 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[245] ./dist/apps/nx-app-server/main.js 39.7 KiB {0} [built]
[261] ./node_modules/@nrwl/nx/esm5/nrwl-nx.js + 17 modules 308 KiB {0} [built]
      |    18 modules
[262] ./server.ts + 1 modules 5.38 KiB {0} [built]
      | ./server.ts 1.81 KiB [built]
      |     + 1 hidden module
    + 358 hidden modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js 18261:15-36
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./server.ts 5:0-47 11:0-14

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js 18273:15-102
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./server.ts 5:0-47 11:0-14

ERROR in C:\Development\Temp\nx-worspace-with-ssr\apps\nx-app-e2e\src\integration\app.spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Development\Temp\nx-worspace-with-ssr\apps\nx-app-e2e\src\integration\app.spec.ts(4,20)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'cy'.

ERROR in C:\Development\Temp\nx-worspace-with-ssr\apps\nx-app-e2e\src\support\app.po.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Development\Temp\nx-worspace-with-ssr\apps\nx-app-e2e\src\support\app.po.ts(1,34)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'cy'.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get the ssr to build by changing the structure of some files.
[View commit here](https://github.com/stefan-karlsson/nx-workspace-with-ssr/pull/1)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that helped me when I built almost the [same](https://github.com/servrox/nx-ng-nest-universal). I used @nestjs/ng-universal as ssr component.

Comment: At Stefan and @servrox thanks a lot guys. I also built the same. I also wrote a blog article on this: https://medium.com/@philip_lysenko/angular-universal-with-nrwl-nx-ca2996a7da2